# align items left in navbar - html & css

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar on the left side of my page and the items in it are not aligned left. what I have found online it should work but it doesn't, so I hope someone can explain it.

---

This is how it looks:
[image]

---

And this part should go

[image]

---

This is my code:

```css
.lkNavbarDiv { 
  height: 100%; 
  position: relative; 
  float: left; 
  width: 20%; 
  max-width: 200px; 
  display: block; 
  z-index: 2; 
  background-color: #E7E9EB; 
  overflow-y: auto; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
} 

ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
} 

.lkNavbar { 
  display: flex; 
  padding: 20px 0; 
  margin: 2px 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  text-align: left; 
  align-items: flex-start;
} 

.lkNavbar.active { 
  background-color: #C9CBCD; 
  border-left: solid #909193;
}
```

```html
<div class="lkNavbarDiv">
  <ul class="">
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/leerkracht/overzicht">
        Dashboard
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/leerkracht/leerlingen">
        Leerlingen
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/leerkracht/bibliotheek">
        Bilbiotheek
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/leerkracht/verander-wachtwoord">
        verander wachtwoord
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar active">
      <a href="/beheer/gebruikers-beheren">
        gebruikers beheren
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/beheer/gebruiker-toevoegen">
        gebruiker toevoegen
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/beheer/boeken-beheren">
        boeken beheren
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/beheer/boek-toevoegen">
        boek toevoegen
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This spacing is caused by the `padding` on the `<ul>`.

If you inspect the element in your browser, you'll see
[image]

Add `padding-left: 0;` to the `<ul>` to remove it.

---

```css
.lkNavbarDiv { 
  height: 100%; 
  position: relative; 
  float: left; 
  width: 20%; 
  max-width: 200px; 
  display: block; 
  z-index: 2; 
  background-color: #E7E9EB; 
  overflow-y: auto; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
} 

ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;

} 

.lkNavbar { 
  display: flex; 
  padding: 20px 0; 
  margin: 2px 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  text-align: left; 
  align-items: flex-start;
} 

.lkNavbar.active { 
  background-color: #C9CBCD; 
  border-left: solid #909193;
}
```

```html
<div class="lkNavbarDiv">
  <ul class="">
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/leerkracht/overzicht">
        Dashboard
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/leerkracht/leerlingen">
        Leerlingen
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/leerkracht/bibliotheek">
        Bilbiotheek
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/leerkracht/verander-wachtwoord">
        verander wachtwoord
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar active">
      <a href="/beheer/gebruikers-beheren">
        gebruikers beheren
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/beheer/gebruiker-toevoegen">
        gebruiker toevoegen
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/beheer/boeken-beheren">
        boeken beheren
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lkNavbar">
      <a href="/beheer/boek-toevoegen">
        boek toevoegen
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```